# Change a users cursor icons globally

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to create a simple application (Windows Forms .NET) for myself in Visual Studio that changes that replaces the default cursor icons but do not have much experience with C#.

These are the cursor settings I'm trying to change:
[image: Settings I'm referring to]

How would I go about this?

I haven't found any way to do this yet.

Comment: Do you have "much experience" with any language that might be able to do this?  What made you choose C++, a language you do not have much experience with?

Comment: I put C++ by mistake, but I am fluent in Lua. I didn't choose C# it was the only option I had, I would rather use Lua but don't know how I would be able to use it with Visual Studio.